# Node: How to decode a win1255 file

Tags: node.js, express, encoding, iconv, libiconv

I just trying to decode a win1255 encoding file with node server.

I found a solution! with Iconv lib:

```
const decode = content => {
  const iconv = new Iconv('CP1255', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE');
  const buffer = iconv.convert(content);
  return buffer.toString('utf8');
}
```

and that was good enough (under macOS...), ***BUT*** when I tried to run it on a Windows Server 2012 (prod server) I got an error, thats Iconv lib is not supported under win32.

So I tried to solve it with iconv-lite, but i found that iconv-lite is not supporting win1255 / cp1255 encoding.

Error in win server:

> iconv.node is not a valid Win32 application

So in truth I feel helpless.

hope that someone could help me to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: note that i solved that issue, for those who encountered this problem: try run node-gyp rebuild at node_modules/iconv library.